# How to integrate Console2 over Cygwin (WinXP)?

Tags: windows-xp, cygwin, console2

I have installed [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=81523) and Cygwin too. I like to run Cygwin terminal as Console2. So i want to integrate Console2 over Cygwin. I have seen other guys use Cygwin like that. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a batch script's path in the tab's `Shell` field, with this as its contents:

```
@echo off

set path=%PROGRAMPATH%\cygwin\bin;%PROGRAMPATH%\cygwin\usr\X11R6\bin;%PATH%
set SHELL=/bin/bash
set CYGWIN=codepage:437
set HOME=/home/paradroid

%PROGRAMPATH%\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i
```

Obviously, you will need to edit the Cygwin path and the username for the home directory.

Comment: Woww! Thats works!! Thats so great and thanks!! Additionally, let me know-- What is `%PROGRAMPATH%` ? I used static "C:" for that.

Comment: @4lvin: It's an environmental variable example which I said you would need to alter to fit the way you have things set up.

Comment: Thanks paradroid. It works for me now. Do you have a way to change the details color theme of `Console`?

Comment: @4lvin:  I'm not sure what you mean, but I just alter the standard ANSI colours in the Console2 settings slightly (lighter) so that they display nicely across all shells I use.  If you want to change specific colour settings in Cygwin you will need to edit your `.bashrc`.

Comment: @4lvin https://github.com/mztriz/Console2-Twilight-Theme