# Running Irssi in a Cygwin (bash) shell inside of the Console 2 wrapper

Tags: windows-7, bash, cygwin, irssi, console2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to integrate Console2 over Cygwin (WinXP)?](https://superuser.com/questions/315060/how-to-integrate-console2-over-cygwin-winxp)

I downloaded the source for irssi (a command line IRC client) and compiled it, following instructions, with Cygwin.

Normally when I run Cygwin it opens mintty.exe and runs in that, but I know that mintty isn't compatible with Console 2, a wrapper that I'd like to use, however Console 2 is compatible with bash.exe and so is Cygwin.

If that didn't come across clearly:

> I want to run irssi (IRC client) in Cygwin (linux command line
>   environment in Windows) in a bash.exe instance, under the Console 2
>   wrapper.

If I open bash.exe on it's own and run irssi in that, it runs perfectly well, but trying to run it once I've opened bash in Console 2 spits out the following error:

```
/cygdrive/c/irssi/bin/irssi.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Suggestions? Ideas? Info you need that I failed to provide? Anything would help.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong when it doesn't tell you what library it cant load. Try running `strace /cygdrive/c/irssi/bin/irssi.exe`, it might give you some more info on what it can't load.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and it responded "bash: strace: command not found"
I get this error whether I open it under Console 2 or open bash.exe on it's own.

As an aside, I tried using the > markup in this comment like you edited into my original question, but it didn't work. What gives?

Comment: `strace` is installed at `/usr/bin/strace.exe` in my cygwin. But I install **a lot** of extra packages when I install cygwin. As to the editing, the `>` requires an empty line above it to work you can read about it here: http://superuser.com/editing-help

Comment: Looking in my cygwin folder, I have strace.exe at `C:\cygwin\bin\strace.exe` which is the same folder that I'm running `bash.exe` from, should I `cd` into `cygwin/bin` before running the command?

e: Tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: 1) does this works in real console window? 2) give a try to ConEmu http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560 (another console emulator)

Comment: If I run a normal Cygwin instance (which uses `mintty.exe` rather than `bash.exe`) then `strace /cygdrive/c/irssi/bin/irssi.exe` spits out a massive amount of information.    

If I use `bash.exe` on it's own, it doesn't work and likewise with `bash.exe` inside of Console 2.
  
I didn't see it listed in the information about ConEmu, can it entirely remove the window border/title so it's nothing but text with a transparent background?

Comment: I looked around some more on Super User and found a question asking how to integrate Console 2 and Cygwin, and using the method there appears to have resolved my problem. Presumably it was something to do with improperly loading bash. The question can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/315060/how-to-integrate-console2-over-cygwin-winxp?rq=1

Comment: @Read, ConEmu has hundreds of options. And yes, you may entirely remove title and border. Quake mode may be selected too. There is a tag "conemu" here on superuser, you may ask questions about it.